# Javascript - difference between namespace vs. closure?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures, terminology, definition

In Javascript, what's the difference between a namespace and a closure?  They seem very similar to me.

*EDIT*

Specifically, [this article](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/advanced-javascript/) discusses namespaces and closures, and has sentences like

> Now, we’re still going to have situations where we’ll want to declare
>   variables that don’t naturally fit into a namespaced object
>   structure. But we don’t want those variables to have a global scope. This is where
>   self-invoking functions come in.

It goes on to give what looks a lot like a closure, as an "object namespace".  It looks to me like the namespace IS a [closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)...but maybe it's not...? Help?

Comment: Elaborate on your definition of a "namespace".

Comment: Javascript doesn't have namespaces.  What do you mean by that term?

Comment: There is no one meaning of "namespace" in javascript because there are many ways to accomplish the task of separating symbols into spaces (including with closures). Show some code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A namespace is essentially an `Object` with no interesting properties that you shove stuff into so you don't have a bunch of variables with similar and/or conflicting names running around your scope. So, for example, something like

```
MyNS = {}
MyNS.x = 2
MyNS.func = function() { return 7; }
```

A closure is when a function 'retains' the values of variables that are not defined in it, even though those variables have gone out of scope. Take the following:

```
function makeCounter() { 
   var x = 0;
   return function() { return x++; }
}
```

If I let `c = makeCounter()` and then repeatedly call `c()`, I'll get `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. This is because the scope of the inner anonymous function that `makeCounter` defines 'closes' over `x`, so it has a reference to it even though `x` is out of scope.

Notably, if I then do `d = makeCounter()`, `d()` will start counting from 0. This is because `c` and `d` get different instances of `x`.

Comment: This is a really good answer - thanks!  Gonna give it some time though :)

Comment: +1 I finally understand closures (and I have tried like 2-3 tutorials and always gave up)

Comment: Yeah, this is most concise and helpful explanation of closures I've seen - thanks! Now I get it.

Comment: I kind of feel like this is a great answer regarding closures, but I'm still not clear on why they are different than namespaces. Where are you getting your definition of namespace, it's pretty specific and my impression of namespace is simply a named context in which no two objects can have the same name. To my mind, that means a closure is a type of namespace.

Answer (score 5):

A namespace is typically a method of putting all your global variables as properties under one master global variable, thus only adding one new truly top-level global variable.  It prevents pollution of the global namespace and reduces the chance of conflict with other global variables.

And example of a namespace:

```
var YUI = {};
YUI.one = function(sel) {...};
YUI.two = function(sel) {...};
YUI.three = function(sel) {...};
```

There is one new item in the top-level global namespace `YUI`, but there are multiple globally accessible items via the YUI namespace object.

A closure is a function block that lasts beyond the normal finish of the execution of the function because of lasting references to internal parts of the function.

```
function doSometing() {
    var x = 10;
    setTimer(function() {
        // this gets called after doSomething() has finished executing
        // but because of the function closure, the variables 
        // inside of the parent scope like x are still accessible
        x += 10;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/:

> A closure is formed by returning a function object that was created within an execution context of a function call from that function call and assigning a reference to that inner function to a property of another object. Or by directly assigning a reference to such a function object to, for example, a global variable, a property of a globally accessible object or an object passed by reference as an argument to the outer function call.

Namespaces are just a convention, objects created to avoid cluttering the global scope with variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @GeoffreyHing! Thanks for the help but seems to me that the "closure" paragraph is overly complicated and extremely confusing...but the namespace explanation is clear and concise, +1.